# Qt Widget with tree organized items

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qlistview

I'd like to have an widget with items organized in tree structure. However it should be viewed in one line and every substree should be represented in braces. For example:

**1. element1 2. element2 3. element3** (*3. element31 4. element41 {4. element43 5. element53}  5. element 51 6. element61* 3. element32 4. element 42) **4 element4 5. element5**

Each element should also have an associated icon and should be clickable. I think about QListView or QTreeView. The second one sounds better but I have to idea how to force it to display items in such manner.

Comment: No You have to make your own custom view here. Its a lot of work. but If don't want it clickable then you can just serialize it to json and then print

Comment: You probably have to implement your own view, based on abstract one. But before you start coding, you should understand, how user will expand/collapse items, what happens, if your tree is 100 levels high, what happens, if you have 1000 elements on the top level?

Comment: Items won't be collapsable. It should be expanded all the time. And tree won't be so high and so wide. I'm sure that implementing my own view will be a lot of work - it sound like overkill here.

Comment: Then, should user interact with tree somehow?

Comment: Yes, user should be able to select a particular element.

Comment: If user don't need to interact don't write a view just serialize it to json and then print.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is still to implement your own view. As far as user interaction with view is rather limited, it should not be so difficult ([see](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-chart.html) Qt's example of pieview, yours should be simpler).

Alternatively, you can just create an array of styled buttons (smth like this:)

```
//stylesheet:
QPushButton {
     background-color: white;
     border-width:0px;
    border-style:none;
 }
 QPushButton:pressed {
     background-color: blue;
     color:white;
 }
 QPushButton:checked {
     background-color: darkblue;
     color:white;
 }
```

Every button then will represent one item in your view.